# Hide Proceed to Checkout in Wordpress/WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using Wordpress and WooCommerce and I need help adding two user roles. I got it working with one role, but need to also apply this to another role.

Below I am using user role 'wholesale', but there is also another user role that this rule needs to apply to 'us_wholesale'.

Here is my code in functions.php:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wdm_wu_minimum_order_amount' );

function wdm_wu_minimum_order_amount() {

    $current_screen_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( in_array( 'wholesale', $current_screen_user->roles ) ) {

      $minimum = 150;

    if ( WC()->cart->subtotal < $minimum ) {
       if( is_cart() ) {
           wc_print_notice(
               sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' ,

                   wc_price( $minimum ),
                   wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )
               ), 'error'
           );

       } else {
           wc_add_notice(
               sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' ,

                   wc_price( $minimum ),
                   wc_price( WC()->cart->subtotal )

               ), 'error'
           );
       } } } }
```

And my override in woocommerce cart-totals.php:

```
<?php

   $current_screen_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( in_array( 'wholesale', $current_screen_user->roles ) ) {

      $minimum = 150; // Set the minimum amt.
      $cart_amt = WC()->cart->subtotal; // cart sub_total, this is actual total excluding discounts and shipping.

                if ( $cart_amt < $minimum ) {
          if( is_cart() ) {
        //Added notices for cart page.
              wc_print_notice(
                  sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' ,
                      wc_price( $minimum ),
                      wc_price( $cart_amt )
                  ), 'error'
              );
          } else {
        //Added notice msg for checkout page.

              wc_add_notice(
                  sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' ,
                      wc_price( $minimum ),
                      wc_price( $cart_amt)
                  ), 'error'
              );
          }
      } else {
          do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' );
      }
    } else {
      do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' );
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have two roles you're checking, why not just replace the following line:

```
if( in_array( 'wholesale', $current_screen_user->roles ) ) {
```

with

```
if( in_array( 'wholesale', $current_screen_user->roles ) || in_array( 'us_wholesale', $current_screen_user->roles ) ){
```

That way your current (presumably working?) functions will run if the current user has either `wholesale` or `us_wholesale` as a user role.